# How to set true in ProgressRing

Tags: c#, .net

I ran into a weird problem. I need to set Busy = true to return new Command (() => this value should be accepted by ProgressRing. The fact is that in the case of return new Command (() something goes wrong ...

```
<Controls:ProgressRing Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" IsActive="{Binding Busy}"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Height="40" Width="40"/>

 public ICommand Test
        {
            get
            {
                Busy = true; // This work
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    Busy = true; //This not work
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense at present. What do you expect to happen? How is the `Command` implemented and triggered? Why the `Async-Await` tag?